# Why do I get "invalid operands of types 'const char*'" error?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I am making an Arduino alarm. This is the error:

```
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Here is the code that triggers it:

```
lcd.print("0"+hours+":"+minutes);
```

This code is similar, but worked before:

```
String none="00";
lcd.print(none+":"+none+":"+minutes);
```

I can post the full code if you need it. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first code took a `String` object, then added other strings (note lowercase) to it - which are characters enclosed in quotes. It is legal to add strings to `String` objects.

Your new code doesn't have any `String` objects at all - and you're not allowed to add strings to strings (both lowercase).

It will work if you change your new code to:

`lcd.print(String("0")+hours+":"+minutes);`

That turns the original string `"0"` into a `String` object, and then adds more strings to it.